# How do I create a file if the file does not exist?

Tags: c++11, fstream

I am currently trying to create a file after trying to open it, if it does not exist. 
I would like to do this without the use of `ios::app` because with this, I would not be able to use the seek function in the future.

My includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fstream>
#inlcude <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

My main:

```
string str;
cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
cin >> str;
fstream fstr;
fstr.open("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::ate );
if (fstr.fail()) {
    cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
    fstr.open("test.txt", ios::out);
    fstr.close();
    fstr.open("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::ate );
} // if file does not exist, create by using "ios::out",close it, then re-open for my purpose

if (fstr.is_open()) { // if the file opens/exists
    fstr << str << endl; // str goes into fstr
    fstr.close(); // close
}
```

The code above seems to be working fine, but I just wanted to be open for any other advice, other suggestions or alternate methods of achieving the same goal. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that `ios::app` prevents you from subsequent [seekp()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)

Comment: I thought the `ios::app` forced seekp() to go to the end of the file no matter what making the seekp() useless, correct me if I am wrong as I am still studying this language.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use the *stat()* function, which is available on Unix based systems and also Windows. Then you could write a very simple function that test if a filename exists and names a file:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

bool FileExistAndIsFile(const std::string & filePath)
{
    int result;
    struct stat statBuf;

    result = stat(filePath.c_str(), &statBuf);
    return ((result == 0) && S_ISREG(statBuf.st_mode)) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: This soultion is vulnerable to race conditions

Comment: You probably mean that processA can stat() with the intention to open() in the sequence, but a processB might delete the file in between the stat and open calls, correct? Then yes, there is this possibility.